# Copying a large file from portable hard drive to another in Windows results nothing

Tags: windows

I'm trying to copy mu music-library (about 125gb) to another portable hard drive. However, When I try to do it, Windows' copy-alert just pops and then goes away. I've also tried to first copy them on C:\ without any progress. All of the drives are NTFS.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to copy 1 file from HDD1 to HDD2. If that works then perhaps you are trying to copy too much at once and should break up the transfer into smaller chunks.

Personally, I use tools to do mass transfers. [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy) is my favorite to keep libraries in sync.

Comment: +1 on the try 1 file and see what happens. I'd suggest Robocopy to copy them it will give you messages as to why it won't copy.

Comment: I had robocopy in my original post. But low rep prevented me from putting any more links in my post... I read more than I answer

Comment: One file and even few folders go nicely. Maybe I just have to transfer in parts. Is there any good tutorial for Robocopy? I tried that also, but didn't really know how to use it :)

Comment: The Wiki page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) provides a nice "Quick Start" under the common usage.   
In the external links, there are links to the Robocopy GUI and RichCopy as well as the Robocopy command line reference tool.  

But probably:  

    `robocopy C:\foo C:\bar /E`  


Will copy Foo to Bar, recursively and including empty folders (as per the wiki)

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I actually already left SyncToy on and it seems to have made the job. Thanks still!